# Sql IN analog in boost::multi_index

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index, multi-index

I use boost::multi_index and retrieve data like this:

```
sample_set::index<my_indx>::type::iterator s, end;
boost::tie(s,end) = samples.get<my_indx>().equal_range(
    boost::make_tuple( "Dress", "Red" ));
```

This code retrieves all red dresses. Is there any way to retrieve red and yellow dresses with one query? Like in SQL:

```
"Select * from clothes where type = 'Dress' and color in ('Red', 'Yellow')"
```

Comment: It looks like you can write your own compares with a composite_key_compare http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/key_extraction.html#composite_key_compare

Answer (score 3):

There's no way of doing that with one single operation: Boost.MultiIndex lookup member functions always return *ranges* (or iterators, that can be thought of as one-element ranges), but the result of such a query as you describe is not a range --its elements are not necessarily adjacent. So you've got to do two queries, one for ("Dress","Red") and one for ("Dress","Yellow"), and then traverse the two resulting ranges in sequence.

Comment: Could one filter the container (indexed range) with Boost Ranges filtered? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html